# Invalid Credentials when using Magento Akeneo PIM Connector

Tags: akeneo

I'm using the latest version of Akeneo PIM; Version:2.3.21 and Magento 1.9.

I'm trying to create a credential instance in PIM, I followed the instructions from the Magento Akeneo PIM Connector documentation page; https://webkul.com/blog/magento-akeneo-pim-connector/

When I go to create the instance, I enter the credentials and in the log it says invalid credentials and I know 100% they are correct.

Under hostname I tried http://url, url, url's ip and i get the same error everytime any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution for anyone else who may run into this. My magento store url was https:// so when i tried using http:// well that's why it wasn't working.

So I just went into the magento backend and changed the unsecure/secure url settings so that the url reflected http:// and then it worked fine.

So once logged into magento backend, System -> configuration -> web.